# How to move UIView by longPress on button and then dragging?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, long-press

I want to move some UIView by button inside this view.
I can it, in that way:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(dragBegan:withEvent:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(dragMoving:withEvent:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(dragEnded:withEvent:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
}
```

.

```
    - (void)dragBegan:(UIControl *)c withEvent:ev {

    UITouch *touch = [[ev allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

}

- (void)dragMoving:(UIControl *)c withEvent:ev {
    UITouch *touch = [[ev allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
 //This is moving view to touchPoint
SimpleView.center = touchPoint;


}

- (void)dragEnded:(UIControl *)c withEvent:ev {

}
```

How can i move it only then, if I do longPress on that button?

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272333/combine-longpress-gesture-and-drag-gesture-together)?

Comment: Yes, but how can I recorganize touch event in this?

Comment: Wait, are asking for the x and y values of `touch` in your dragMoving and dragBegan methods? If so, look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733868/can-ipad-iphone-touch-points-be-wrong-due-to-calibration).

Comment: That I know, but how can I use it in UILongPressGestureRecognizer?

Answer (score 8):

Try using this code. I've used this in a card game i developed. moving cards around using long press gestures. Hope i helps.

```
 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(addLongpressGesture:)];
 [longPress setDelegate:self];
 [YOUR_VIEW addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

- (void)addLongpressGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {

UIView *view = sender.view;

CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:view.superview];

if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){ 

  // GESTURE STATE BEGAN

}
else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged){

 //GESTURE STATE CHANGED/ MOVED

CGPoint center = view.center;
center.x += point.x - _priorPoint.x;
center.y += point.y - _priorPoint.y;
view.center = center;

// This is how i drag my views
}

else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){

  //GESTURE ENDED
 }
```

Comment: You didn't understand! I need to longpress on button and drag the MY_VIEW, in same touch!

Comment: well you add the gesture recognizer on your UIButton and in the UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged you manipulate the points of your MY_VIEW

Answer (score 1):

I would use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272333/combine-longpress-gesture-and-drag-gesture-together) provided by @Coder404 to detect whether or not the player used a long touch. Then, add an `@property BOOL performedLongTouch` and set that to `YES` in the `selector` passed into the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`

Then, in your `dragBegan` and `dragMoving` functions, add a check for `performedLongTouch` and in your `dragEnded` function, set its value to `NO`

I know that seem pretty straight forward, but is that what you were looking for?

Comment: There need to longPress and then touch again for move, but I need to do it by longPress and move!